# Is there a maximum pain threshold?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology, pain, injury

> **Is there a maximum threshold of pain a Human can experience, beyond which point there is no noticeable difference?**

I ask this question in part to better understand the definition of pain and its different facets, e.g. Is there a quantitative measure of pain? Are there various types of pain, or are they all part of the same fundamental experience?

It would also be interesting to know since I could perhaps be allowed to claim:

> "well at least I know I cannot feel more pain than X"

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: it only goes to 10. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_scale  ha ha just a little levity

Comment: "But this one goes to 11!"

Comment: Haha! Interesting how many scales there are, cheers

Answer (score 3):

When the pain receptors are fully loaded then it's not possible to excite these receptor greater. However the perception of pain has a large psychological component and is not well understood. Your brain could modulate your perception of pain naturally or due to illness.